# Event constraint from business hours per resource

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-premium

How would I go about setting the eventConstraint property to use the business hours held at a resource level.
The documentation talks about setting it at the top businessHours level, or being able to restrict to certain resources.
I have resources with different business hours, but still want to apply the eventConstraint to them

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that if you set `eventConstraint: "businessHours"` it doesn't do this automatically? Can you provide a [mre] of the scenario with some sample data for resources and business hours? Also what version of fullCalendar are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As per ADyson comment, eventConstraint: "businessHours" makes it work.
The documentation made me think you had to build the businessHours object