# Fullcalendar how to unset an option

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Following on from my previous question: [Event constraint from business hours per resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922936/event-constraint-from-business-hours-per-resource)

How can you 'unset' an option in fullcalendar?

I use this to set something:

```
calendar.setOption('eventConstraint', "businessHours");
```

I now want to have a toggle to set and unset this option to allow this or not.

I have tried:

```
calendar.setOption('eventConstraint', "");
```

But that has no effect

Thanks